# Android ImageButton in different screens

Tags: java, android, screen, imagebutton

In the UI for my application I have 5 `ImageButton` all is ok on the 3.7" screen but if I have a screen of 2.7", 3.0" or other my UI will not scale and it looks bad. It looks like this:

3,7"

[image]

2,7"

[image]

How do I make all have a nice look on all screens, just like on the screen 3.7"?

Code: main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/two"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibTest1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/one" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibTest2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/one" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibTest3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/one" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibTest4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/one" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibTest5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/one" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use dp , and relativelayout , 
another tip : is create your images in mdpi , ldpi , and hdpi format  , ( another tip : is using ninePatch images :) )

Answer (score 1):

Use a `RelativeLayout`, and then place a `LinearLayout` with height `wrap_content` and put the buttons inside that LinearLayout. Also use `dp` instead of `px` for sizes.

P.S. If you post the code of your layout, we can help you better.

EDITED: Now that I can see your code I can show you want I meant with my answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/two"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibTest1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/one" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibTest2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/one" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibTest3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/one" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibTest4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/one" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibTest5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/one" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but something did and it does not solve my problem, because the buttons have to be lower because the main UI where the background is added on top is the inscription of "icons"

Comment: It's a `RelativeLayout` you can add anything you want before the `LinearLayout` and then position the `LinearLayout below whatever you put before and place it on top of the `RelativeLayout` and that will push the buttons down..

Comment: I know, but my point is that I have a background with the logo on top and underneath it I want to have buttons on the emulator 3.7 "everything looks good, but if someone has a screen 2.7" buttons to move up and obscure the logo.
No way do they simply had declined along with the background?

Comment: Why don't you just place the logo in an `ImageView` inside the `RelativeLayout` and let the `LinearLayout` be placed on top of that when there's no space?

Comment: Only, then this arrangement will look ugly on larger screens ...
I'll just separate screens for different layouts.

Comment: @defus.nex It depends on how you arrange the views.. but the option to set different layouts is also valid and good

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some code?
Maybe try add to  in xml

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: My code? I do this only for test... I have Relative layout + 5 ImageButton it's all.

Answer (score 0):

First make image for all

> mdpi,hdpi,ldpi

as per their size.

take Lineatlayout in center for Buttons only.

then set property gravity="Center" ;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are using `dp` insted of using `'px'`..Its a common cause.

Answer (score 0):

try this add in each imageview in xml

```
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```